# галерея на grid css

Tags: javascript, css, grid

есть галерея выполненная на css grid

```
.gall{
display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 8px;
  grid-row-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  }
```

возможно ли обойти равную высоту строки чтобы убрать пустое расстояни между картинками
[image: см. скрин]
все изображения разных размеров и к одному виду не привести в шопе...
как убрать обведенное пространство. на js тоже можно. спасибо!

Comment: Не использовать grid. Гуглить css masonry

Comment: Нормально, пусть использует грид, если картинки такого вот вида, пусть этим занимаются контент менеджеры (если их нет, пускай найдут). Не нужно придумывать очередные хаки "как это все исправить".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто оставлю это здесь как пример.

**[Источник](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/)**

```js
/**
 * Set appropriate spanning to any masonry item
 *
 * Get different properties we already set for the masonry, calculate 
 * height or spanning for any cell of the masonry grid based on its 
 * content-wrapper's height, the (row) gap of the grid, and the size 
 * of the implicit row tracks.
 *
 * @param item Object A brick/tile/cell inside the masonry
 */
function resizeMasonryItem(item) {
  /* Get the grid object, its row-gap, and the size of its implicit rows */
  var grid = document.getElementsByClassName('masonry')[0],
    rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap')),
    rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));

  /*
   * Spanning for any brick = S
   * Grid's row-gap = G
   * Size of grid's implicitly create row-track = R
   * Height of item content = H
   * Net height of the item = H1 = H + G
   * Net height of the implicit row-track = T = G + R
   * S = H1 / T
   */
  var rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.masonry-content').getBoundingClientRect().height + rowGap) / (rowHeight + rowGap));

  /* Set the spanning as calculated above (S) */
  item.style.gridRowEnd = 'span ' + rowSpan;

  /* Make the images take all the available space in the cell/item */
  item.querySelector('.masonry-content').style.height = rowSpan * 10 + "px";
}

/**
 * Apply spanning to all the masonry items
 *
 * Loop through all the items and apply the spanning to them using 
 * `resizeMasonryItem()` function.
 *
 * @uses resizeMasonryItem
 */
function resizeAllMasonryItems() {
  // Get all item class objects in one list
  var allItems = document.getElementsByClassName('masonry-item');

  /*
   * Loop through the above list and execute the spanning function to
   * each list-item (i.e. each masonry item)
   */
  for (var i = 0; i > allItems.length; i++) {
    resizeMasonryItem(allItems[i]);
  }
}

/**
 * Resize the items when all the images inside the masonry grid 
 * finish loading. This will ensure that all the content inside our
 * masonry items is visible.
 *
 * @uses ImagesLoaded
 * @uses resizeMasonryItem
 */
function waitForImages() {
  var allItems = document.getElementsByClassName('masonry-item');
  for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) {
    imagesLoaded(allItems[i], function(instance) {
      var item = instance.elements[0];
      resizeMasonryItem(item);
    });
  }
}

/* Resize all the grid items on the load and resize events */
var masonryEvents = ['load', 'resize'];
masonryEvents.forEach(function(event) {
  window.addEventListener(event, resizeAllMasonryItems);
});

/* Do a resize once more when all the images finish loading */
waitForImages();
```

```css
:root {
  counter-reset: masonry;
}

.masonry {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 0;
}

.masonry-item {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.masonry-item {
  background-color: #eee;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.masonry-item,
.masonry-item img {
  position: relative;
}

.masonry-item:after {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  content: counter(masonry);
  counter-increment: masonry;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all .1s ease-in;
}

.masonry-item:hover:after {
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.4/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/800?image=1" alt="Masonry Brick #1" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/600?image=2" alt="Masonry Brick #2" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=3" alt="Masonry Brick #3" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=4" alt="Masonry Brick #4" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/700?image=5" alt="Masonry Brick #5" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/300?image=6" alt="Masonry Brick #6" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=7" alt="Masonry Brick #7" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/650?image=8" alt="Masonry Brick #8" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/350?image=9" alt="Masonry Brick #9" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/420?image=10" alt="Masonry Brick #10" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/300?image=11" alt="Masonry Brick #11" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=12" alt="Masonry Brick #12" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/550?image=13" alt="Masonry Brick #13" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/900?image=14" alt="Masonry Brick #14" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/800?image=15" alt="Masonry Brick #15" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=16" alt="Masonry Brick #16" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=17" alt="Masonry Brick #17" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/650?image=18" alt="Masonry Brick #18" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/550?image=19" alt="Masonry Brick #19" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/440?image=20" alt="Masonry Brick #20" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/480?image=21" alt="Masonry Brick #21" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/680?image=22" alt="Masonry Brick #22" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/920?image=23" alt="Masonry Brick #23" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/650?image=24" alt="Masonry Brick #24" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/350?image=25" alt="Masonry Brick #25" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/425?image=26" alt="Masonry Brick #26" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=27" alt="Masonry Brick #27" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/450?image=28" alt="Masonry Brick #28" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/350?image=29" alt="Masonry Brick #29" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/900?image=30" alt="Masonry Brick #30" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/520?image=31" alt="Masonry Brick #31" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/650?image=32" alt="Masonry Brick #32" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/750?image=33" alt="Masonry Brick #33" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/800?image=34" alt="Masonry Brick #34" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/900?image=35" alt="Masonry Brick #35" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/420?image=36" alt="Masonry Brick #36" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/350?image=37" alt="Masonry Brick #37" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/600?image=38" alt="Masonry Brick #38" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/480?image=39" alt="Masonry Brick #39" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/640?image=40" alt="Masonry Brick #40" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/350?image=41" alt="Masonry Brick #41" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/380?image=42" alt="Masonry Brick #42" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/420?image=43" alt="Masonry Brick #43" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/500?image=44" alt="Masonry Brick #44" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/640?image=45" alt="Masonry Brick #45" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/680?image=46" alt="Masonry Brick #46" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/700?image=47" alt="Masonry Brick #47" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/350?image=48" alt="Masonry Brick #48" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/400?image=49" alt="Masonry Brick #49" class="masonry-content"></div>
  <div class="masonry-item"><img src="https://unsplash.it/700/800?image=50" alt="Masonry Brick #50" class="masonry-content"></div>
</div>
```